# Can openstack instance have multiple interface network cards?

Tags: openstack

I want to create an instance in openstack with multiple Network interface card

I always has only one interface for SSH or other things
I need more interface to use dpdk.

**So my question is that can OpenStack instance have multiple interface, and how to make instance with multiple interface using linux cli?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely yes.

There is two methods to achieve this at least:

- 1, create instance with **multiple interfaces** by specify option argument **`--nic`** multiple times, check the snip help message:

```
# openstack server create -h
usage: openstack server create (--image <image> | --volume <volume>)
                               --flavor <flavor>
                               [--nic <net-id=net-uuid,v4-fixed-ip=ip-addr,v6-fixed-ip=ip-addr,port-id=port-uuid>]
                               <server-name>

Create a new server

positional arguments:
  <server-name>         New server name

optional arguments:
  --nic <net-id=net-uuid,v4-fixed-ip=ip-addr,v6-fixed-ip=ip-addr,port-id=port-uuid>
                        Create a NIC on the server. Specify option multiple
                        times to create multiple NICs. Either net-id or port-
                        id must be provided, but not both. net-id: attach NIC
                        to network with this UUID, port-id: attach NIC to port
                        with this UUID.
```

- 2, add another interface to an instance with `server add port` or other command like this: "[latest/cli/command-objects/server.html](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest/cli/command-objects/server.html)", such as:

```
openstack server add port

openstack server add network
```

One more thing, it also could create instance with multiple interfaces by `nova-API` request, the network parameter is `array` type, and it could define your requirement, check from "[create-server-detail](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/?expanded=create-server-detail)".